# eslint one-var and padding-line-between-statements rules 'overlap'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, lint, rules

I've setting up a webpack config and I want to use the following code convention

Use one-var, but if the next declaration is an arrow function, let that be declared elsewhere, I don't want it to be combined with previous const declarations in the scope.

I've read many rules and issues but I haven't found anything that fits what I'm looking for.

I found a way to separete the arrow function from the previous declarations with the padding-line-between-statements rule, but then one-var insists they are declared together and doesn't allow a blank line between them.

Expexted result:

```
const test1 = 1,
      test2 = 2;

const test3 = () => {console.log(test1, test2)};
```

What I've got now:

```
const test1 = 1,
      test2 = 2,
      test3 = () => {console.log(test1, test2)};
```

I'm getting "Combine with previous const" from one-var rule in eslint.

Answer (score 0):

ESLint finally fixed the bug where multiple vars were being checked in for statements!

you can also add this setting into your eslint configs

```
"one-var": [2, { initialized: "never" }]
```